# How can I update the available Android APIs in Eclipse (ADT)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, api, adt

I am trying to update my API level choices within eclipse. Currently, the highest I can get to is API 19:

-

### [image: API Availability]

I am interested in starting with 5.0 and making that my target API, but I cannot seem to get it as an available option.

I have tried updating eclipse via the help -> check for updates, but have seen nothing new.

Currently, I am using the ADT via eclipse (See picture below)

-

### [image: Android ADT]

I am sure it is something very simple that I am missing, but can someone tell me where I can find the update to this so that I can start working with things like the glass API, wearables, and Lollipop? Is there a section for updating that I have not seen? Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Steps for updating eclipse

```
 1. Download eclipse from the official site
 2. Download and install jdk latest version
 3. After installing the eclipse , Go to  Help > Install New Software.
 4. Click Add, in the top-right corner.
 5. In the Add Repository dialog that appears, enter "ADT Plugin" for the     
        Name and the following URL for the Location:
        https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
 6. Click OK.
 7. In the Available Software dialog, select the checkbox next to Developer Tools and click Next.
 8. In the next window, you'll see a list of the tools to be downloaded. Click Next.
 9.Read and accept the license agreements, then click Finish.
 10. If you get a security warning saying that the authenticity or validity of the software can't be established, click OK.
 11. When the installation completes, restart Eclipse.
```

After restarting eclipse , goto android sdk manager .

Now you will see all the android versions and tools